# Is there an undead-heavy adventure that takes PCs from level 1 to level 20?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, campaign-development, published-adventures, undead

Is there either a single adventure or a collection of linked adventures that meets the following criteria:

- The primary foes are undead creatures.
- The adventuring sites include maps.
- The adventure includes an interesting plot.
- The adventure or adventures take the player-characters from level 1 to level 20 (or nearly so).

The adventure or adventures don't necessarily have to be absolutely complete or foolproof. Instead, I plan to use the adventure or adventures as a template for crafting my own campaign, and I'd like to read a similar amateur or published example before I begin.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.Stackexchange.com.  Please take a look at the [About] page when you have a chance.

Answer (score 5):

### Adventure Paths

You're looking for an Adventure Path, published by Paizo.  For 1-20 they are widely regarded as the most interesting, easy to run, and well-designed campaigns.  The older ones were released in Dungeon magazine and also as printed hardcover collections for 3.5e, the newer ones are released for Paizo's 3.5e re-release, Pathfinder.

For an undead related one in the 3.5e ruleset, I recommend [Age of Worms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Worms).

It doesn't actually have a compiled release, so you will have to purchase pdfs of the magazines separately from paizo's website.

Something which is compiled, although doesn't deal as heavily with undead, is the [Shackled City](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ysn?Dungeons-Dragons-The-Shackled-City-Adventure-Path-Hardcover) campaign.

I've used them both, and found them easy to run, coherent, and generally well-written.  Worth using and will probably be fun for your players.

Answer (score 3):

Paizo Adventure Paths are generally the answer to questions like this.  The most "undeady" of these is the [Carrion Crown Adventure Path](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventurePath/carrionCrown), which I just got done playing in.  It's a gothic horror adventure path, so it's not 100% undead, but full of ghosts, vampires, werewolves, frankensteins, cthulhus, and liches. It is OK, though a little railroaded at times, you'll want to adapt it a little. You can read [all our session summaries and thoughts on the campaign here](http://geek-related.com/session-summaries/carrion-crown/).

It's chock full of maps and plot and art like all the APs.  It goes through level ~14, but has add-on info in chapter 6 to take it further.